# Saving Textbox value to Cache on Button Click

Tags: c#, caching, button

I have a textbox and a button,

how do I save the Textbox value to cache when button has been clicked?

when I say Cache I mean to use Application Cache. not variable. I want to use the value throughout the application session so using Session wouldn't work.

I am using a web application in Visual Studio, this example is within a web form.

Regards
Rob

Comment: To cache? Do you mean a variable?

Comment: Do you mean ASP.NET?

Comment: What is your project type? It's winforms, wpf, asp.net mvc/web forms?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to Trouble you with a poor post, but I managed to sort out what I was trying to do, and as usual, it was quite easy just hard to find.

I Created two web forms,

Form 1 had a button and text box

Form 2 had a button and label.

Code from web form 1 below.

```
 protected void BtnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Cache["UserName"] = TbxSave.Text;

        Response.Redirect("RetreiveFromCache.aspx");

    }
```

Code from Web form 2 below

```
    protected void BtnRetreive_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        String value;

        value = Cache.Get("UserName").ToString();
        Label1.Text = value;

    }
```

Sorted.